# Finding ranks and nullities of linear maps

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, vector-spaces

I am confused about ranks, nullities and bases of the kernel.
From what I understand the rank is the dimension of a vector space generated by a matrix.

How would I do the following examples?

> Find the ranks and nullities of the following linear maps $T \colon U \to V$, and find bases of the kernel and image of $T$ in each case.
>
> (i) $U = \mathbb{R}^4$, $V = \mathbb{R}^4$, $T(\alpha, \beta, \gamma, \delta) = (\alpha - \gamma, \gamma-\delta, \alpha-\beta, \beta-\delta)$;
>
> (ii) $U = \mathbb{R}[x]_{\leq 5}$, $V = \mathbb{R}[x]_{\leq 5}$ (polynomials of degree at most $5$ over $\mathbb{R}$), $T(f) = f'''$ (third derivative of $f \in U$).

([Source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ldsyX.png))

Comment: Please consider posting the question in MathJax.

Comment: Do you know how to find the matrix corresponding to a linear transformation?

Comment: Nullity is the dimension of the nullspace. Are you familiar with the nullspace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For (i), let's start with the kernel. Suppose $T(a,b,c,d)=(0,0,0,0)$. Then $(a-c,c-d,a-b,b-d)=(0,0,0,0)$ which implies $a=b=c=d$. Therefore the kernel is the
subspace generated by $\{(a,a,a,a)\}$ for some $a\in\mathbb{R}$. This has dimension (nullity) equal to $1$.

Now by the rank-nullity theorem, the rank is $3$. If you haven't seen this theorem then the matrix of $T$ is equal to

$$\begin{pmatrix}1&0&-1&0\\0&0&1&-1\\1&-1&0&0\\0&1&0&-1\end{pmatrix}$$

(try to calculate this yourself or at least convince yourself of why it's true)

You can row reduce this to get the rank, which should equal $3$ like we've said.

For (ii), you just need to compute the matrix of $T$ again.

Answer (score 2):

Note that for the second exercise a basis for $V=\Bbb R[x]_{\le 5}$ is given by: $(1,x,x^2,x^3,x^4,x^5)$. To calculate $\ker$ and $ImT$ consider the matrix taking this basis. $$A=\begin{pmatrix}0&0&0&6&0&0\\0&0&0&0&24&0\\0&0&0&0&0&60\\0&0&0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0&0&0\end{pmatrix}$$ Now you can calculate $\ker A$ and $Im A$

Comment: I am not sure exactly how to do it. Do you mind expanding on your answer?

Comment: To calculate the ker you have to solve a linear system:$$A=\begin{pmatrix}0&0&0&6&0&0\\0&0&0&0&24&0\\0&0&0&0&0&60\\0&0&0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0&0&0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\\z\\l\\g\\k\end{pmatrix}=$$A=\begin{pmatrix}0\\0\\0\\0\\0\\0\end{pmatrix}$$

Comment: I got Dimension=6, rank=2, nullity=4. The kernel is found by Ax=0 where A is the matrix. Hence it would be all polynomials of degree 2 or less in this example?

Comment: No the rank of this matrix is 3

Comment: Ah yeah. Then nullity must be 3 as well because of the rank-nullity theorem.

Comment: If Rank is 3 the ker is 3 by nullity+rank